# Python 3.8: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable when trying to get data from a file

Tags: python, oop

ran into a roadblock during a tutorial. I have no idea on how to solve this. I'm trying to use data from a csv file. When I try accessing the data with the current code commented out (see below), it works by outputting existing data.

[image]

However, it immediately errors when I add back in the commented code, with the error mentioned in the title. Could someone look at this and tell me what I've done wrong?

```
import csv

class item:
    pay_rate = 0.8 #the payrate after 20% discount
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity: int = 0):
        #run validations of received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"price {price} !> 0"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"quantity {quantity} !> 0"


        #assign to self object
        print(f"an instance created: {name}")
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

        #actions to execute
        item.all.append(self)




    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)

        for item in items:
            item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=float(item.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item.get('quantity')),
            )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"item({self.name},{self.price}, {self.quantity})"

item.instantiate_from_csv()
print(item.all)
```

[image]

Comment: What did you expect that to do?  `item` is the name of a dictionary.  What is your objective with that?  And is that in a class called `item`?  Do not reuse names like that.  It just leads to confusion.

Comment: Why is the code raising the exception commented out?

Comment: `item` is a `dict`. What do you expect `item(...)`  to do? Are you maybe trying to create an instance of class `Item`? That would be `item=Item(...)`.

Comment: You're using `item` like it can be anything at any time. Even in Python, that's not possible.

Comment: What I am trying to do is take code from a csv file, pull the data out and then process it (this is part of a tutorial I am following). Unfortunately, I get that error and I have no idea what I need to do to fix it. I will edit my main post with the full code.

Comment: You've named everything `item` and managed to confuse even yourself. But clearly the `item` causing the issue is the one where you are looping over a list of dictionaries, calling each `dict` element in the list `item` and then trying to access that dictionary as if it were the constructor of the class you also called `item`. Start by renaming the various things you named `item` to be something more descriptive and distinctive, and you'll see that the problem is obvious then.

Answer (score 0):

By naming several things `item`, you managed to confuse even yourself.

Below is your code with things sensibly renamed and the problem fixed. Take a look at the comments to see what was changed:

```
import csv


# renamed to AllItems, because that's what you end up using it for
# you're mixing up an instance and a container of instances here and
# it gets you the worst of both worlds
class AllItems:
    pay_rate = 0.8
    all = []

    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity: int = 0):
        assert price >= 0, f"price {price} !> 0"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"quantity {quantity} !> 0"

        print(f"an instance created: {name}")
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

        # you can do this, but you in some cases you want to use
        # self.all.append instead, which will still access the class
        # attribute
        AllItems.all.append(self)

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        # this is dubious - can you apply the same discount many times?
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    # renamed to 'load', sure you instantiate, but you don't return the
    # instance, you're really just abusing the class as a container
    @classmethod
    def load_from_csv(cls, fn):
        # it seems to make more sense to be able to use different csvs?
        with open(fn, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            item_dr = list(reader)

        for item_dict in item_dr:
            # your problem was right here, you referred to `item()` where
            # you meant to refer to the class, which is already passed as `cls`
            cls(
                name=item_dict.get('name'),
                price=float(item_dict.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item_dict.get('quantity')),
            )

    def __repr__(self):
        # I'm not fixing this, but see remark below
        return f"item({self.name},{self.price}, {self.quantity})"


AllItems.load_from_csv('items.csv')
# confusing double `.all` here, didn't bother improving the naming
# considering that it's the result of the design decision you made
print(AllItems.all)
```

For an `items.csv` with this:

```
name,price,quantity
banana,10,12
apple,4,6
pear,7,6
```

Output:

```
an instance created: banana
an instance created: apple
an instance created: pear
[item(banana,10.0, 12), item(apple,4.0, 6), item(pear,7.0, 6)]
```

Note that this fixes your issue but still leaves your code with some serious problems:

- You're using the class as a container; that works, but it's not a great way of using a class like this and it certainly won't be what others expect. You're robbing yourself of all of the features a better container like a `list` would get you, like the it being iterable, or a `dict`, which would allow easy lookup of products (items). Consider creating an `Item` class that is just the `Item` and an `Items` (or something better) class that contains items and has additional operations.
- Note that your representation `__repr__` really doesn't give you a representation, that's not how someone could recreate the class at all and it's probably more of a `__str__`

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting:

```
import csv


class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8

    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity: int = 0):
        assert price >= 0, f"price {price} !> 0"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"quantity {quantity} !> 0"

        self.name = name
        self._price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.discount = None

    @property
    def price(self):
        if self.discount is None:
            return self._price
        else:
            return self._price * self.discount

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_pay_rate(self):
        self.discount = self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def item_list_from_csv(cls, fn):
        with open(fn, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            item_dr = list(reader)

        return [cls(
            name=item_dict.get('name'),
            price=float(item_dict.get('price')),
            quantity=int(item_dict.get('quantity')),
        ) for item_dict in item_dr]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.name}, {self.price}, {self.quantity})"


item_list = Item.item_list_from_csv('items.csv')
print(item_list)
print([item.total_price for item in item_list])
```

Output:

```
[Item(banana,10.0, 12), Item(apple,4.0, 6), Item(pear,7.0, 6)]
[120.0, 24.0, 42.0]
```